# MySql and Mybatis select distinct rows where value <= ##

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

I've got three tables:  Users, Roles, Authorites

**Users**

```
|username|lastName|firstName|....
|dan     |foo     |dan
|russ    |bar     |russ
```

**Roles**

```
|role                 |roleLevel
|ROLE_ADMIN           | 0
|ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN   | 20
|ROLE_MARKETING_ADMIN | 50
|ROLE_SERVICE_ADMIN   | 80
|ROLE_USER            | 100
```

**Authorities**

```
|username|authority
|dan     |ROLE_SERVICE_ADMIN  |
|dan     |ROLE_USER           |
|russ    |ROLE_MARKETING_ADMIN|
|russ    |ROLE_ADMIN          |
|russ    |ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN  |
```

I need to get all the DISTINCT users that have a roleLevel higher than the INT I pass in AND their lowest roleLevel

What I have now is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.username, u.firstName, u.lastName, r.roleLevel FROM AUTHORITIES a, ROLES r, USERS u
WHERE r.role =  a.authority
AND a.username = u.username 
AND r.roleLevel >= #{roleLevel} 
ORDER BY u.lastName, u.firstName
```

but that gives me multiple rows for users with multiple roles.  How can I get the users with a lower roleLevel than what I passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you multiple rows because you haven't specified that you want the lowest; plus you've used a greater than not a lower than.

```
SELECT u.username, u.firstName, u.lastName, min(r.roleLevel) minroleLevel
  FROM AUTHORITIES a, ROLES r, USERS u
 WHERE r.role =  a.authority
   AND a.username = u.username 
   AND r.roleLevel <= #{roleLevel}
 GROUP BY u.username, u.firstName, u.lastName 
 ORDER BY u.lastName, u.firstName
```

Comment: see my comment to Doug above.  The role granting the most access is ROLE_ADMIN which has a roleLevel of 0.  So its all backwards to me.  Your comment is correct based on how my question was worded so I had to edit my question I do indeed want r.roleLevel >= #{roleLevel}

Comment: BTW Thank you for your response. It is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I should have realised; it's fairly obvious once you look at the names!

Comment: I've had a chance to try this. It's close but not quite. If a user has an authority lower than what I passed in, it should not show up on the list.  When a user has multiple roles (0, 10, 100) and I pass in 10, the user should not show up on the list (because of the 0).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a user can have multiple rows, you need to determine how you want to display the roles.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.username, u.firstName, u.lastName, 
    max(r.roleLevel) largestRoleLevel,
    min(r.roleLevel) minimumRoleLevel,
    GROUP_CONCAT(r.roleLevel SEPARATOR ', ') allRoleLevels
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN AUTHORITIES a ON a.username = u.username
INNER JOIN ROLES r ON r.role = a.authority

WHERE r.roleLevel >= #{roleLevel} 
GROUP BY u.username, u.firstname, u.lastname
ORDER BY u.lastName, u.firstName
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(r.role_level SEPARATOR ', ') allRoleLevels should be GROUP_CONCAT(r.roleLevel SEPARATOR ', ') allRoleLevels

Comment: Note - I just noticed that your condition (`r.roleLevel >= #{roleLevel`) didn't seem to match what you asked for - "... a roleLevel lower than the INT I pass in"

Comment: Good catch on role_level. Sorry about that. Typing without testing and all.

Comment: yes its all confusing because its "backwards" for me...the 'highest' role or the role granting the most access on the site is ROLE_ADMIN which has a roleLevel of 0.  So I edited my question to ask for the roleLevels higher and I still want that users's lowest roleLevel

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    u.username, u.firstName, u.lastName, 
    min(r.roleLevel) minRoleLevel
FROM 
    authorities a 
    JOIN roles r ON r.role = a.authority
    JOIN users u ON u.username = a.username
GROUP BY 
    u.username, u.firstName, u.lastName 
HAVING 
    minRoleLevel >= #{roleLevel}
ORDER BY 
    u.lastName, u.firstName
```